# Which version of python do I have to download for pyscripter?

Tags: python, x86, 64-bit, x86-64, pyscripter

so basically I'm trying to install pyscripter for my computer, and am aware that Python 2.4 or higher is needed to run the program.

My computer specs, first of all, are:
Windows 10 (64bit)
Intel CPU
4GB ram
(or at least the important ones)

Now when I go to python.org, there are about a thousand different downloads available like 'Python 3.7.0a1' or '3.6.3rc1' or '2.7.14', most of them being x86, and some of them having x64 next to them which I am assuming is 64 bit, and some of these files are a .zip file, executable file, MSI installer etc. What I want to know is:

1. Which one of these do I have to download for my system?
2. Does MSI matter?
3. Does x64 mean that the file is going to be 64 bit?
4. Does installing version 2 or version 3 (I am aware of the differences between version 2 and version 3) change the way that pyscripter runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Which one of these do I have to download for my system?

You can install 2.7.14 version of python to run pyscripter. On a seperate note you can intall/run multiple versions of python on your machine if you want/require.

2. Does MSI matter?

It's a installer for microsoft operating systems.

3. Does x64 mean that the file is going to be 64 bit?

Yes

4. Does installing version 2 or version 3 (I am aware of the
   differences between version 2 and version 3) change the way that
   pyscripter runs?

No - However you can configure pyscripter to use a specific version of python as per the requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped a lot for a starter to python like me!

Comment: And hope it helps others who want to know as well!

Answer (score 0):

I used pyscripter too for a while but eventually you have to switch to something more modern. As far as I remember it works up Python 3.4.4 and then stops. Also they no longer develop it.

My advice is start with an editor that is being developed (I use Pycharm and they have a free of charge community edition). You will eventually need all those plugins and version controll support, database interactions etc. etc. all in one package.

This way you learn an editor that has a future. Don't repeat my mistake of learning Pyscripter and then realising it is not supported anymore and Python 3.6 does not work on it :).

I started not so long ago as well.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

PyScripter supports all python versions from 2.5 up to 3.7 both 32-bit and 64-bit.  Just make sure you use the 32-bit version of PyScripter with 32-bit versions of Python and the 64-bit version of PyScripter with 64-bit versions of Python.